# Number of section contains the number of the chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

In my table of contents, i have 2 chapters "chapter1 and chapter 2" the introduction of chapter 1 has a number 1.1 and in the chapter 2 it has a number 2.1 
I ask please how can set only the number 1 to the introduction not 1.1 ?
How can i begin the numerotation from section 1 not from the introduction ?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{zzz}

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction \thechapter}

blah

\section{abc}
Abc
\section{abcd}
Abcd

\chapter{WWW}

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction \thechapter}

blah

\section{abc}
Abc
\section{abcd}
Abcd


\end{document}
```